# JSON writing to file doesnt update, just replaces

Tags: javascript, json, error-handling, puppeteer

So I have been scouting the forums for hours, and I can find nothing, so its time to make a post.

My issue is, I am using 'Faker' to generate a username and password. That works perfectly fine, but when I try and save the username + password to the JSON it just saves the exact same username and password to each ID. I want the ID to start at 0 and go up to lets say 10, but with each section being different.

```
    const username = faker.internet.userName();
    const password = faker.internet.password();
    await waitingFirst.type(username);

    var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
    var obj={
         'table':[]
        };

    for (i=0; i <5 ; i++){
           obj.table.push({"id":i,name:username,pass: password});
    }
    jsonfile.writeFile('user.json', obj, {spaces:2}, function(err){
          console.log(err);
    });
}
```

So what this code does, is gets the faker generated username and password, and bungs it into the JSON, but as I said.

First of all :

`{
  "table": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Roger61",
      "pass": "SWoHIOYFOTSKN12"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Roger61",
      "pass": "SWoHIOYFOTSKN12"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Roger61",
      "pass": "SWoHIOYFOTSKN12"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Roger61",
      "pass": "SWoHIOYFOTSKN12"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Roger61",
      "pass": "SWoHIOYFOTSKN12"
    }
  ]
}`

As you can see it updates the ID correctly, but it doesn't generate a new one each time, so my example would be the next one would look like this :

```
    {
  "table": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Libbie_Medhurst65",
      "pass": "gxvca3glaT_xOeg"
    }
  ]
}
```

but instead my code just replaces all of them, and doesn't give me a new ID, it only allows set ID's.

Im hoping someone can help, thank you in advance, please comment if you need help describing it.

(Im trying to store USER + PASS in plaintext(for personal) to test some register stuff)

Comment: You are pushing the same value inside loop - `obj.table.push({"id":i,name:username,pass: password});` You should generate the username and password inside loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling Faker once and then looping through 5 times, you need to call Faker every single time to get a new result.

```
  var obj={
    'table':[]
  };

 for (i=0; i <5 ; i++){
   let username = faker.internet.userName();
   let password = faker.internet.password();
   obj.table.push({"id":i,name:username,pass: password});
 }
 jsonfile.writeFile('user.json', obj, {spaces:2}, function(err){
   console.log(err);
 });
```

Comment: hello, yes I came to the conclusion that would work, but my next problem is in the for statement 
(i = 0; 1<5; i++) how can i make it so that each time the script is run it adds a new line inside of the JSON, so everytime its run one is added into user.json

Answer (score 0):

What i understand over here is that username and password is not updating, only id is updated.

```
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile'); 

var obj={ 'table':[] }; 

for (i=0; i <5 ; i++){ 

let username = faker.internet.userName(); let password = faker.internet.password();
obj.table.push({"id":i,name:username,pass: password});

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call

```
const username = faker.internet.userName();
const password = faker.internet.password();
```

in the loop where you are trying to push it in the table 
also

```
var obj={
     'table':[]
    };
```

instead you can do

```
const table = [];
for (i=0; i <5 ; i++){
       table.push({"id":i,name:username,pass: password});
}
const obj = {
   'table': table
};
jsonfile.writeFile('user.json', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)), 
{spaces:2}, function(err){
      console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: hello, thank you for that.
My other problem which I haven't been able to resolve is the fact that I have to select via i how many I have, i would like it to go + 1 each time